# Facebook's Messaging Feature Review API giving permission error for page editors

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook page listed in Facebook NPI. I am an editor of that page. When I am trying to check the subscription/news messaging permission status programmatically using this api:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messaging-feature-review-api/?hc_location=ufi

I am getting the following permission error:

> (#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page. If the page business requires Two Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor Authentication.

But when Facebook page owner calls this API, it returns the status successfully.

Can anyone tell me why page editor is getting the permission error?

Answer (score 1):

Guess that is simply considered a page management action you do not have access to using that “role”.

Roles have been replaced by Tasks by now, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview-1#tasks

The only difference in the tasks they can perform, between old Admin and Editor roles, was MANAGE - so I guess you will need to have a page admin approve your user account for that task on the page now first, if you want to be able to use this particular API.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. That might be the reason